# Error при загрузке apk на Google play

Tags: java, android, apk

Загружаю apk на Google play получаю ошибку:

> "You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a
>   zip align tool on your APK and upload it again.".

Прочитала, что для этого нужно набрать в командной строке:

```
zipalign -v 4 your_project_name-unaligned.apk your_project_name.apk
```

Получаю в командной строке ошибку:

> zipalign: command not found

Что я не так делаю? И как это сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобралась в чем проблема, во-первых я была не в правильной директории, я была в директории  apk файла, а нужно быть в директории: `~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/xxxx/zipalign`, где xxxx - версия, во-вторых перед командой поставила `"./"`, а именно    `./zipalign -v 4 your_project_name-unaligned.apk your_project_name.apk` и все заработало.